# Absorption Curves Normalization

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy, absorption

I have absorption curves for three species that are nominally the same concentration that I need in order to calculate spectral overlap. Part of that process is dividing the curve through by the concentration as a normalization process. The curves of two species are a factor of 10 lower than the other (not necessarily a problem), but that is true even out away from where the peaks from these species are. All curves were taken on the same spectrometer. It seems to me like maybe someone changed out the blank solvent in-between data taking (a possibility in a shared lab). Is there a way to normalize this prior to calculating spectral overlap?

Comment: Are the data recorded on a two-beam instrument, where sample and blank are simultaneously present?  If so, the _raw_ spectral data accessible to you (prior baseline correction, peak pick, etc.) may already be the result of subtracting the signal of the blank from the signal of your sample (= no recovery).  Note, some spectrometer's software allow the user to define (i.e., to change) which of the two paths is about the sample, or the blank; an additional _potential_ pitfall in a shared lab.  Suggest: Add an illustration of the curves here, clarify the aim to "calculate the spectral overlap".

Comment: Otherwise, if you may normalize _by maximum intensity_ (most intense peak in each spectrum = 1.00 a.u.) and then set the three spectra in one diagram in common.  Then, it it might have been a good thing that each sample's concentration was similar to each other.

Comment: I am calculating spectral overlap for resonant energy transfer reasons which unfortunately means I can't divide through by the maximum value. It is a two-beam instrument, and I've just realized that I saved the original data file type in addition to the csv. I'll check if that has the needed information to get the raw curve back out. Thank you

Comment: Ok, it is not for "looking nice" (to advertise the location of the bands) in first place, but for a FRET. A look at this [overview](http://www.fluortools.com/software/ae/documentation/edit-spectra/normalize) regarding normalizing, and [FRET](http://www.fluortools.com/software/ae/documentation/tools/j) em particular may be helpful.  Sadly, though, it is not a walk-through including the .cvs data.

Comment: @MJAFort do you really need the normalisation if the species had the same concentration? Because if the answer is yes, I can not see at this moment how one would proceed, - at all - with different concentrations.

Comment: @Alchimista I am suspicious that there is something gone wrong due to the fact that the absorption far away from the peaks from these species is a factor of 10 higher as well as the peaks due to the species. I guess I was trying to figure out if there were normalization processes that are commonplace but I was unaware of, especially given all the rules surrounding the calculation of the spectral overlap integral. Nominally all solutions in this case were 1mM

Comment: Isn't it possible to check for the absorption of that one compound? To see if it should have somewhere a zero Abs between peaks? It might be genuine? Molecules might have very different absorption coefficients...